# In Pandas, how can I convert a "long" table to a "wide and sparse" table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sparse-matrix

My terminology is horrible so this one deserves some explanation.  Imagine that I have a DataFrame like this (which I call the "long" table):

```
time       stock     price
---------------------------
13:03:00   AAPL      100.00
13:03:00   SPY       200.00
13:03:01   AAPL      100.01
13:03:02   SPY       200.01
13:03:03   SPY       200.02
.
.
.
```

and I wanted to convert it to a DataFrame like this (which I call the "wide and sparse" table):

```
time       AAPL      SPY
---------------------------
13:03:00   100.00    200.00
13:03:01   100.01    Nan
13:03:02   Nan       200.01
13:03:03   Nan       200.02
```

So obviously this is quite a transformation.  Is there a built-in function that does this?  It seems like it might be a pretty common thing to want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='stock', values='price')
print (df)
stock       AAPL     SPY
time                    
13:03:00  100.00  200.00
13:03:01  100.01     NaN
13:03:02     NaN  200.01
13:03:03     NaN  200.02
```

Another solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['time', 'stock']).price.unstack()
print (df)
stock       AAPL     SPY
time                    
13:03:00  100.00  200.00
13:03:01  100.01     NaN
13:03:02     NaN  200.01
13:03:03     NaN  200.02
```

But if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Is necessery use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function, default `np.mean`.

```
print (df)
       time stock   price
0  13:03:00  AAPL  100.00
1  13:03:00   SPY  200.00
2  13:03:01  AAPL  100.01
3  13:03:02   SPY  200.01
4  13:03:03   SPY  200.02
5  13:03:03   SPY  500.02 <- duplicates for same time and stock 


df = df.pivot_table(index='time', columns='stock', values='price')
print (df)
stock       AAPL     SPY
time                    
13:03:00  100.00  200.00
13:03:01  100.01     NaN
13:03:02     NaN  200.01
13:03:03     NaN  350.02
```

Another possible solution for duplicates `time` and `stock`:

```
df = df.groupby(['time', 'stock']).price.mean().unstack()
print (df)
stock       AAPL     SPY
time                    
13:03:00  100.00  200.00
13:03:01  100.01     NaN
13:03:02     NaN  200.01
13:03:03     NaN  350.02
```